# calling redux connect on a decorator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, gatsby

I am trying to call `connect` on a decorator that returns a react class

```
const SetLanguageFromPage = () => {
  return WrappedComponent =>
    class setLang extends React.Component {
      static propTypes = {
        pathContext: PropTypes.shape({
          language: PropTypes.string.isRequired
        })
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        const currentLanguage = i18n.language;
        const pageLanguage = this.props.pathContext.language;

        // First request
        if (!currentLanguage) {
          i18n.language = pageLanguage;
        }

        // Only update on language change
        if (currentLanguage !== pageLanguage) {
          i18n.changeLanguage(pageLanguage);
        }
      }

      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { return{...} }
const mapDispatchToProps = (dis) => { return{...} }

export default connect(...)(SetLanguageFromPage);
```

but when I then use the decorator on another react class I get this error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
```

which I suppose is from `connect` changing my function to a react class. Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do? I would really like to be able to call actions to set the state from within this decorator, but I can't see how I can get at the `store` to call `dispatch` or map the dispatch to the props...

I am using https://www.gatsbyjs.org/ for this, so the general method has the store instantiated in a way where I cannot access is directly

Answer (score 0):

You get an error, because you are trying to pass and HOC to connect, whereas it expects a React component. You can instead connect the returned component inside the `HOC`, which is what you essentially want to do

```
const SetLanguageFromPage = () => {
  return WrappedComponent => {
    class SetLang extends React.Component {
      static propTypes = {
        pathContext: PropTypes.shape({
          language: PropTypes.string.isRequired
        })
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        const currentLanguage = i18n.language;
        const pageLanguage = this.props.pathContext.language;

        // First request
        if (!currentLanguage) {
          i18n.language = pageLanguage;
        }

        // Only update on language change
        if (currentLanguage !== pageLanguage) {
          i18n.changeLanguage(pageLanguage);
        }
      }

      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }

    };
    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SetLang);
   }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { return{...} }
const mapDispatchToProps = (dis) => { return{...} }

export default SetLanguageFromPage;
```